# UIWebViews in UITableView do not render while the table is being scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView with UIWebViews within the cells for the purpose of displaying rich text. The UITableViews load html strings locally. However, when the table is being scrolled, the UIWebViews do not load the html strings specified in "cellForRow..." until the UITableView stops scrolling. Is there any way to override this behaviour so that the UIWebViews load content even when the tableview is scrolling?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this version. For the record, it affects UITextViews as well (no surprise, as they render with WebKit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible at this time for performance reasons. The best way to work around this issue is to render any downloaded content directly onto a UIView by overriding drawRect.